Question from the Proof of the Classification of Finite Subgroups of SO(3)
On page 14 here, the author sets up the following situation: say we have an order 12 subgroup $G$ of $SO(3)$ acting on the poles of $G$ (i.e. on the set of vectors on $S^2$ fixed by some non-identity element of $G$) in such a way that there are exactly three orbits of sizes 6, 4, and 4, respectively. Let $z$ be in the third orbit $O_3$, and let $u$ be any element of $O_3$ which is not $\pm z$. Notice that the stabilizer $G_z$ of $z$ has size 3 (by Orbit-Stabilizer), hence is cyclic, generated by a rotation $g$ by $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ about the line through the origin parallel to $z$. Since $g$ is an isometry, it is easy to check that $u$, $gu$, and $g^2u$ are equidistant from $z$ and sit at the corners of an equilateral triangle. This is all fine.
The author then claims that "Similarly, if we look at the orbit starting from any other points, say $u$, we see that $z$, $gu$, and $g^2u$ are equidistant from $u$ and lie at the corners of an equilateral triangle."
Why is this true? I seem to be able to draw pictures that indicate otherwise (imagine $z$ as the north pole and $u$ as very close to it, spherically speaking, for example).
